# Can we harvest some of the energy from hurricanes to provide an electricity resource?

Tags: energy

http://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/can-we-capture-energy-hurricane-180960750/
from this article...
"The wind from just one storm is a gold mine of clean energy." 
"The energy output from the wind is about 1.5 terawatts from your average cyclone."

Comment: Any thoughts?  Is there research ongoing?  How far out is this thinking?

Comment: You are asking two very different questions (more if you consider the above comment). Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: You would need very special wind turbines, a *lot* of them to catch enough of the hurricane's energy, and you would only use them a few days each year (if at all). Also, given the damage and need to rebuild, I wouldn't call a hurricane particularly *clean*.

Comment: This is like asking if we can nuke the greenhouse gasses out of the atmosphere. Just because there is energy there doesn't mean we can use it to someone stop global warming.

Comment: If by "ironic," you mean "impossible," sure.

Comment: Define "clean the atmosphere". Define "reduce global warming". Define "unbelievable energy". Unless and until you can do that, I'm voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Actually, it is the lightning that 'cleans the air'. See [effects of lightning](https://www.nasa.gov/home/hqnews/2003/mar/HP_news_03110.html)

Comment: There is no such thing as a stupid question. There are only stupid answers because the responder can not see all of the ramifications of the question. ANY question can lead to legitimate answers of some sort. Even if it is an answer that sheds light on the complexity of the question, and leads to clarification. I don't think any question that is not offensive should be put on hold. Even the child's question 'Why is the sky angry tonight? It is so red.' can lead to useful answers.

Comment: @nareshneel yes there IS legitimate research being conducted on similar questions. It is a VERY big question, which requires a LOT of research, as to the effects of hurricanes on the environment in general (the feedback effects of a hurricane). It is a legitimate question, 'Can a hurricane, by virtue of the energy dissipated, affect global warming to some degree?' We are harnessing cloud seeding to effect drought and rainfall. Such questions are not moot. Would the tremendous cloud cover  or water vapor from multiple hurricanes  occurring today reflect sufficient solar energy away from earth?

Comment: What would a world that had a balanced status condition between energy expenditure of a  hurricane and solar input into the atmosphere look like? How many hurricanes would be required? What would be their frequency? Will, in fact, increased frequency of hurricanes put an upper limit on global temperature rise? Are we headed there?

Comment: The edited question still seems a little short, but it's answerable now so I'll vote to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

It's not worth it even if you could trap the energy.

You'd need a massive, specially designed wind farm, huge storage facilities all for the remote chance of a hurricane. Hurricanes don't follow a set path so where do you place the farm?

You'd be better off making an ordinary wind or solar farm to collect energy normally for the 99.99% of the time when there is no hurricane.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated. If a hurricane devastated a wind farm, I'd say that there would be a huge output of electricity into the power grid, but the grid would probably fail due to being ripped apart by a hurricane. But, if talking about technology in the future, which I assume is okay, as you didn't put 'currently' in your question, then yes. Tiny fan nanobots, released into a hurricane, would generate a lot of power from the... hurricane-force winds.